# Any solution to make slider to grid and grid to slider conversion

Tags: html

i want to make a team slider with 5 slides in a row but it move in a loop , so when as first slide scroll it render again after last one in a circle it scrolling.

2nd check i want a button " expand " when click on it, the slider convert into grid .

animation request when click on expend button the other slides will show below the slider with fade in.

when click on button shows the first five slide and rest of them are in a grid below the slider.

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.